# How to create mask tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Creating tensor of certain depth with Value 1 for the given indices

Indices Tensor :

```
[[1 3]
 [2 4]
 [0 4]]
```

Output tensor (depth=5) :

```
[[0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the above by first converting to full indices and then use `sparse_to_dense` function to set those index values to 1.

```
#Get full indices
mesh = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(indices.shape[1]), tf.range(indices.shape[0]))[1]
full_indices = tf.reshape(tf.stack([mesh, indices], axis=2), [-1,2])

#Output
[[0 1]
 [0 3]
 [1 2]
 [1 4]
 [2 0]
 [2 4]]

#use the above indices and set the output to 1.
#depth_x = 3, depth_y = 5
dense = tf.sparse_to_dense(full_indices,tf.constant([depth_x,depth_y]), tf.ones(tf.shape(full_indices)[0]))

# Output
#[[0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
#[0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
#[1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Comment: Hi @vijay m, thank you for the solution help. The above works fine with following edit : ones  = tf.ones( ( tf.shape(full_indices)[0], ) )

Answer (score 0):

Silimar solution to @vijay m's, but use a more direct function `tf.scatter_nd`

```py
#Get full indices
mesh = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(indices.shape[1]), tf.range(indices.shape[0]))[1]
full_indices = tf.reshape(tf.stack([mesh, indices], axis=2), [-1,2])

#Output
[[0 1]
 [0 3]
 [1 2]
 [1 4]
 [2 0]
 [2 4]]
 
updates = tf.constant(1.0, shape=(tf.shape(full_indices)[1]))
scatter = tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, shape)
sess.run(scatter)
#
# output
#
array([[0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Hi @walkerlala thank you for your help. But you have defined updates tensor to be static. However its shape depends on full_indices.

Comment: @cseuser123 Can be easily change to suit you need (editted).

Comment: thank you, the above solution works fine too with the edit.